# fix position for wizard window in extjs

Tags: extjs, wizard

I have use wizard window in extjs application. It open at center of window when i start application, but when I drag it somewhere and close it and then again open it theh it opens at the same position where I dragged it. It should be open at center. Please let me know how to fix it. So even if I close wizard at any corner of screen, it should be open again at center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call

```
var yourWindow = new Ext.Window({...});
yourWindow.show();
yourWindow.center()
```

after you show it

Comment: It would be great if you provide me with full syntax as example.